# .ASPXBrowserOverride cookie is set to 7 days

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, session-cookies

My site is having mobile and desktop view, achieved using jquery mobile mvc package (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingASwitchableDesktopAndMobileSiteWithASPNETMVC4AndJQueryMobile.aspx) and it is using `HttpContext.SetOverriddenBrowser` which sets ASPXBrowserOverride cookie with expiration of 7 days.

Is it possible to delete this cookie when we close the browser (session cookie kind of).

Answer (score 0):

What we did to get around this was make the following call in Session_Start in Global.asax.cs:

```
HttpContext.ClearOverriddenBrowser()
```

That made the experience behave as if the cookie was a session cookie. Unfortunately this doesn't give you explicit control over the length of time but we were looking to make it only last a session anyways so it worked well for us.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add...

in ASP.NET MVC you cannot call this method from Global.asax without getting the Wrapper Class

so just do:

```
        var httpWrap = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        httpWrap.ClearOverriddenBrowser();
```